# Expected value and variance of dependent random variable given expected value and variance

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, variance

I have calculated E(Y) for this problem and found it to be 0. However, I am now stuck on Var(Y). I seem to get stuck with either $E(Y^2)$ or $E(X^2)$ when solving it and I'm not sure how to solve those statements.

> Let X be a random variable with expected value $\mu$ and variance
>   $\sigma^2$. Let $Y = (X - \mu)/\sigma$. Compute E(Y) and Var(Y).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
EY^2=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}E[(X-\mu)^2]=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sigma^2=1
$$
by the (original) definition of variance whence
$$
\text{Var}(Y)=EY^2-(EY)^2=1-0=1
$$

Comment: What rule/how is the first part derived?

Comment: Nevermind, I understand now that its using the definition of variance. Thank you